# Getting Text Value of Data-Attribute Link in DOM XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I've tried numerous xpath expressions, evaluations, loops, and so forth.
The best I've gotten is an output of

```
" } object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
```

Someone put me out of my misery by telling me what I'm doing wrong.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$text = urlencode('dog show');
$html = file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=' . $text . '&title=Special:Search&fulltext=Search');
$doc->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars($html));

var_dump($doc);
```

brings it all back, no issues there--

[image]

Now, how do I get the **first** search result back as a text value of the a href `/wiki/Dog_show` and either the `title` or span values embedded within the node list?

I've tried targeting the data attribute `data-serp-pos="0"` which contains what I'm looking for

```
$query = "//a/@href[data-serp-pos=\"0\"]";
$v = $xpath->evaluate($query);
var_dump($v);
```

I've even tried going further up the DOM tree

```
// $query = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul/li[1]/div[1]/a';
// $query = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul/li[1]';
// $query = '//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//a/@href';
```

Tried looping

```
// $result = '';
// foreach ($xpath->evaluate($query) as $p) {
//   $result .= $dom->saveHtml($p);
// }
// var_dump($result);
```

adding `string` in the evaluation, `->nodeValue`, `->item(0)` etc.

The length is always 0.

The entire DIV html is as followed...

```
<div class="mw-search-result-heading"><a href="/wiki/Dog_show" title="Dog show" data-serp-pos="0"><span class="searchmatch">Dog</span><span class="searchmatch">show</span></a></div>
```

What's the (probably simple) solution I'm not doing to get the `href` value and associated link text (or title attribute-- which is the same in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite often I find it easiest to "inspect" the element I wish to target using the developer tools in Chrome from where it is possible to copy the XPath expression that targets that particular node. This doesn't always return the most useful XPath expression but it is usually a good starting point - in this case I tweaked the returned query and added in the classname.

Hope it helps

```
$term='dog show';
$url=sprintf('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%s&title=Special:Search&fulltext=Search', urlencode( $term ) );


printf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', $url, $url );

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;

$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

/* possibly the important bit */
$query='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul/li/div[@class="mw-search-result-heading"]/a';

$col=$xp->query( $query );

$html=array();

if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        $html[]=array(
            'title'=>$node->nodeValue,
            'href'=>$node->getAttribute('href')
        );
    }
}


printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($html,true));
```

Will output:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=dog+show&title=Special:Search&fulltext=Search
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Dog show
        [href] => /wiki/Dog_show
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Show dog
        [href] => /wiki/Show_dog
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Westminster Kennel Club Dog Show
        [href] => /wiki/Westminster_Kennel_Club_Dog_Show
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Dog Eat Dog (U.S. game show)
        [href] => /wiki/Dog_Eat_Dog_(U.S._game_show)
    )

   .......... etc
```

Comment: Pro answer! Very clean code and a more than ideal output. I attempted using the built in chrome xpath finder but apparently not correctly, will have to look into why.. Also brilliant by putting all the reuslts into an array (why not, right?) and some insight into `->nodeValue` and `->getAttribute` for what I was looking to return as well with indexed results easily defined via `$html[0]['title']` / `$html[0]['href']` for the first result `$html[1]['title']` / `$html[1]['href']` the second, etc. Very good thank you!